# convert dropdown to text box when other option is selected

Tags: javascript, html, django, vue.js, frontend

I have a dropdown which displays choices right now it works as just dropdown but when i select the option Other which is a choice when selected it should become textbox.

**models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    task_name = models.CharField(blank=true, choices=somechoiceClass, default='')


<div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group label-static" :class="{'has-error': errors.task_name && errors.task_name.length > 0}">
              <label class="typo__label control-label">Task Name&nbsp;<span class="req">*</span></label>
              <multiselect
                  v-model="form.task_name"
                  :options="taskNameChoices"
                  :multiple="false"
                  :close-on-select="true"
                  :clear-on-select="true"
                  :preserve-search="true"
                  placeholder="Select"
                  label="text"
                  track-by="id"
                  :hide-selected="false"
                  :show-labels="false">
              </multiselect>
              <span class="help-block" v-show="errors.task_name" v-text="errors.task_name && errors.task_name[0]" v-cloak></span>
            </div>
          </div>

<script>
    taskNameChoices: instanceData.case && instanceData.case.task_names || [],
    this.taskNameChoices = selectedOption.task_names;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple job for `v-if` and `v-else`.  Display the multiselect while the selection value is not "Other", else display the textbox.  A very simple implementation would look like this:

```html
<multiselect 
  v-if="form.task_name !== 'Other'"
  v-model="form.task_name"
  :options="taskNameChoices"
>
<input v-else>
```

The `<input>` field would need it's own v-model but how exactly to hook it up is an implementation detail that's up to you.